# Realm crashing app on delete or write, libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, realm, swift5

I have added realm integration in my app. Process is that,
1] if list is not empty then reload the tableview , and at the same time call an api, receive its response..
2] check value present against Id or not, if present delete that value from realm, again add value to realm and reload the tableview.. Code is working fine, if i wait for the 2nd step completion. But 2nd step is totally asynchronous..Here is what I have tried

And crash is happening when i change viewcontroller before the completion 2nd step.

```
public class Features : Object , Codable{
@objc dynamic var intellinectsId : String?
@objc dynamic var serviceName : String?
@objc dynamic var android_icon : String?
@objc dynamic var parentUrl : String?
@objc dynamic var url : String?
@objc dynamic var mobileOrder : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case serviceName = "serviceName"
    case android_icon = "android_icon"
    case parentUrl = "parentUrl"
    case url = "url"
    case mobileOrder = "mobileOrder"
    case intellinectsId = "intellinectsId"
}

required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    serviceName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .serviceName)
    android_icon = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .android_icon)
    parentUrl = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .parentUrl)
    url = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .url)
    mobileOrder = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .mobileOrder)
    intellinectsId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .intellinectsId)
    
}
required init() {
   
}
```

}

I have created single class for RealmService

```
class RealmService {

private init() {}
/// To get singleton class
static let shared = RealmService()
/// To get realm object instance
var realm = try! Realm()

/// To create a record or adding new object to database
func create<T: Object>(_ object: T) {
    do {
        try realm.safeWrite {
            //realm.add(object)
            realm.create(T.self,value: object)
            //realm.create(T.self, value: object, update: .modified)
        }
    } catch  {
        post(error)
    }
}


/// To update/modify particular record/object in the database
func update<T: Object>(_ object: T, with dictionary: [String: Any?]) {
    do {
        try realm.write {
            for (key, value) in dictionary {
                object.setValue(value, forKey: key)
            }
            realm.add(object, update: .all) //add(object, update: true)
        }
    } catch  {
        post(error)
    }
}

/// To delete/remove record or object database
func delete<T: Object>(_ object: T) {
    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.delete(object)
        }
    } catch  {
        post(error)
    }
}

/// To handle the errors while performing realmDB opration
func post(_ error: Error) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: error)
}

/// To observe realm error in the particular View controller
func observeErrors(in vc: UIViewController, completionHandler: @escaping(Error?) -> Void) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        completionHandler(notification.object as? Error)
    }
}

/// To stop observing errors in particular View Controller
func stopObservingErrors(in vc: UIViewController) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(vc, name: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: nil)
}

/// To delete complete realm form the app
func completeDeleteRealm() {
    let realmURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
    let realmURLs = [
        realmURL,
        realmURL.appendingPathExtension("lock"),
        realmURL.appendingPathExtension("note"),
        realmURL.appendingPathExtension("management")
    ]
    for URL in realmURLs {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL)
        } catch {
            post(error)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now in View controller , I am taking a value from realm, against id, like this

```
var dashboardList : Results<Features>{
    get{
        return RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Features.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "intellinectsId == %@", HelperFunctions().getUserInfoFromDefaults()?.intellinectsId ?? ""))
    }
}
```

.. as given in step 1st, if dashboardList count is > 0 then reload the tableview , simultaneously , call and api to fetch the details and again I have performed 2nd step like below

```
if let responseList = response.array, responseList.count > 0{
               
                //remove existing data from realm
                let removeHMC = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Features.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "intellinectsId == %@",intellinectsId))
                if let realm = try? Realm(){
                    try? realm.write {
                        realm.delete(removeHMC)
                    }
                }
                if let featuresList = responseList[0]["features"].array, featuresList.count > 0{
                    for val in featuresList{
                        let feature = Features()
                        feature.intellinectsId = intellinectsId
                        feature.serviceName = val["serviceName"].string
                        feature.android_icon = val["android_icon"].string
                        feature.parentUrl = val["parentUrl"].string
                        feature.url = val["url"].string
                        feature.mobileOrder = val["mobileOrder"].string
                        RealmService.shared.create(feature)
                    }
                }
            }
```

And if i wait for this completion then it works fine. but if i go on next vc. I am getting an error like

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

after looking at the specific issue, I received an error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'
```

I applied [this](https://medium.com/@ludovicjamet/how-to-use-struct-with-realm-615fcbc8f0ee) trick also.. But after deleting value from realm , showing again to the tableview causes this issue. I am unable to figure out. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

In your response when you are deleting the previous features list you are creating a new instance of `Realm()` which will cause inconsistencies between those two.
Try removing that and using the same `RealmService.shared` like this

```
    //remove existing data from realm
let removeHMC = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Features.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "intellinectsId == %@",intellinectsId))
RealmService.shared.delete(removeHMC)
```